# Love the role you're playing in your company

Tags: projects, team-role, personal-problems, job-satisfaction

I am a frontend developer and I love to develop websites. But in my company I am only working on email templates for the biggest client our company has. Yes, I am playing a very important role for that project, but I am bored of working on this project for the last year.

But if some other projects need my help then those project's manager is not allowing me to work on other projects, not even the manager. I have worked on other projects secretly.

I have discussed this issue in my 1-1's with my manager almost every single time for last year and now I am getting other projects, but not a big project or something that I wanted to do.

I feel like I am losing confidence on my technical knowledge and I am stuck. Also I can not grow as a developer. For that reason I don't like this project and not even my job anymore. I also feel like I know every single thing of that project and whenever I think now I'll be facing some issues I'm able to solve them in minutes. That is also a reason I don't like this role as there's no challenge for me!

It'd be very helpful if someone can tell me how to deal with this people or get rid of this project or working on that project and loving it as well. Because I feel without loving a role you can not give your 100%.

Comment: What is keeping you in this job? Have you considered going elsewhere?

Comment: "I have worked on other projects secretly." How do you mean secretly? This is not a good idea for several reasons...

Comment: @seth R where i live there's no such option to get ur desire job very easily

Comment: @HorusKol that mean i have worked on projects but i can not log hours properly and even not was in the public. Not everybody knows about me :)

Comment: @nazifarashid definitely not a good idea - firstly, you're not getting proper recognition for your work; secondly, this will adversely impact the work that everyone thinks you're doing; finally, if something goes wrong with a project and it's discovered that you were "secretly" working on it, that gives the official project team a scapegoat to point to

Comment: Got your point but working on such a project makes me realize that I am learning new things that i don't feel working on my project. But you are right that everything can come on me that's why I am letting my local mentor know and if we don't take risk then how we can prove ourself ?

Comment: "`Also i can not able to grow myself as a developer`" - I don't rely on the gig that pays the rent for that; I learn new skillz on my hobby projects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if you can switch teams.  This will send the message to your boss that you really want to work on something else.  If there are no other opportunities within your company, then you should really start looking outside your company.

When switching teams, make sure that the new team will give you more freedom to work on varied projects, even if their baseline workload is not as interesting.

If you think you can do a good job on another project for another team, work on it secretly until you have a result that you can shop around to demonstrate your initiative and skill.  Then show it to folks and say: "Look at this!  You are not leveraging my full skill set, and the company could be getting so much more from me."  Make sure you find people in management positions that will both be impressed by your work and have the authority to do something about it (i.e., folks above your boss in the org chart).

If nobody else is working on something that interests you, invent an idea that you think will impress high-level folks and build it in your spare time.  Make sure that it actually adds value for the company, and that those Directors/VPs/etc. can easily see the business value they can leverage by taking ownership of your project and shopping it around to the rest of the company.  If you do a really good job, and find the right ambitious/powerful managers within your company, they can form a new team just to take advantage of your under-utilized skills.

Of course, if your work is not actually as good/useful as you think it is, then this is a huge risk.  Make sure you accurately know your value before trying something this bold.

Answer (score 5):

If you've been talking to your manager about this for a year and everything is still the same then **nothing's going to change until you change it yourself**.

You need to look for a role where you'll be working on something you're interested in, in a way that you want to work. That may be another team in your current organisation, or (more likely after talking internally for a year and gaining no traction) it will be a team in a new company.

Either way, your manager isn't going to change this for you, you'll have to be proactive about doing it yourself.

If the type of project you work on is that important to you, then be selective about the interviews you take and ask questions in them to determine if that sort of project is what you'll work on if you get the job. And (most importantly) don't be afraid to turn down job offers if the interview didn't give you confidence that you'd be working in the sort of environment you want.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do something. Your manager is having you do something else. Don't quit your job now.
If you just quit now, you will be selling yourself as a passionate professional with nothing to show for it.

Start doing what you love in your spare time, and complete a few projects from start to end. That will be your portfolio. Once you have 2-3 projects done, start looking for a new job.

Good luck!

Comment: That I'm doing now! I'm working on personal goals in my spare time! But the thing i wanted to know how to deal with my current situation and love my job

Comment: @nazifarashid Acting like this in a short term "wouldn't paint you like a quitter" but in a long run might have negative effects: effectively working 2 jobs (actual job and your own projects) might cause a burn out, you might start hate a job, start to leave on the dot or early (come in late), become a brogrammer (getting rid of these changes is hard), more you work with the stuff that is not relevant to what you want to do more you are degrading in this area and from a CV point of view you are loosing a value. You had this conversation for a year and nothing has changed -- leave.